# Undefined reference to, despite correct link order

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, makefile

I am having trouble linking against an external library, `MY_LIB.a`.

The following is invoked from the makefile created by mbed.org compiler, and with the addition of my link to `MY_LIB.a` path.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs 
-u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -T./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/LPC1768.ld 
-L./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -o MyProg.elf main.o mbed/TARGET_LPC1768
/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/cmsis_nvic.o mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/system_LPC17xx.o
mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/startup_LPC17xx.o mbed/TARGET_LPC1768
/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/board.o mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/retarget.o  
-lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys  -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys 
-L/usr/local/lib/MY_LIB.a
main.o: In function `main':
```

And then I get `undefined reference to <function>` errors for every function defined in `MY_LIB`.

My understanding was that `MY_LIB.a` just needed to be linked after `main.o` which uses it.

I also tried linking (immediately) after `-o MyProg.elf main.o`, but then I get `could not read symbols: File in wrong format`.

What is the correct way to link this library? Does it need to be linked in the previous step to be listed here in.. the correct format? How is that done?

Comment: The usual way would be `-L/usr/local/lib` to add `/usr/local/lib` to the library search path, and then `-lMY_LIB` to actually link to the library (that must be named `libMY_LIB.a`).

Comment: `-L` adds a path, `-l` links a library, you can give a full path to `-l` to avoid needing to use `-L` as well but giving a full path to `-L` like that isn't meaningful.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ah - thank you both, I started wondering what the difference was, should have followed that thought. However with `-L/usr/local/lib/` and `-lMY_LIB.a` I get "cannot find -lMY_LIB.a".

Comment: @EtanReisner Same result. If I just do the full `/path/MY_LIB.a` then I get "could not read symbols" as before.

Comment: Oh, of course, that's not a valid `-l` library name. `-l` expects to be able to form a `lib${arg}.a` filename from its argument. Use adpeace's no dash-argument version if you need to specify a specific file this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-L` only specifies the search path for libraries.  You could remove it from your parameter that is including `MY_LIB.a`, e.g.:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs 
-u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -T./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/LPC1768.ld 
-L./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -o MyProg.elf main.o mbed/TARGET_LPC1768
/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/cmsis_nvic.o mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/system_LPC17xx.o
mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/startup_LPC17xx.o mbed/TARGET_LPC1768
/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/board.o mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/retarget.o  
-lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys  -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys 
/usr/local/lib/MY_LIB.a
```

Comment: I then get "cannot find -lMY_LIB.a"

Comment: @OllieFord Does the first suggestion work? No dash-argument at all?

Comment: @EtanReisner No, I get "could not read symbols: File in wrong format"

Comment: @OllieFord What format is that file in? What does `file` say about it?

Comment: @EtanReisner `current ar archive`

Comment: @OllieFord And `objdump -a MY_LIB.a`?

Comment: @EtanReisner Note also that if I write a small `test.c` file and do `gcc test.c /usr/local/lib/MY_LIB.a` it compiles fine.

Comment: @OllieFord Should trying to link elf32-i386 symbols into an arm binary be working? I would assume you would need an arm library with arm symbols.

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh bugger. Now I feel stupid. So is the issue that when I 'installed' (do you install a library?) the lib, this was done for the host arch? How should I workaround? Can I cross-compile the source into new `.o` files in a new `.a` for arm?

Comment: @OllieFord When you built that library file you built it with the host toolset. You need to build a version of the library with the cross-compilation toolset instead and use that. Note that you don't need to "install" the library into /usr/local for this at all since you can just include a direct path on the link line.

Comment: @EtanReisner So instead of `./configure` I do `./configure --host=arm-none-eabi`?

Comment: @OllieFord When building the MY_LIB library in the first place? Possibly, I'm not overly familiar with the arguments require for cross-compilation with the autotools.

Comment: @EtanReisner If you want to answer that I daftly tried to link elf32-i386, I'll accept that. I may need another question more specifically to help cross-compile the library.

Comment: @OllieFord Accept this answer. It answered the main question. The arch issue was secondary to the undefined reference problem you started with.

Comment: @EtanReisner Well, sort of. I did mention it in OP too. Regardless, I've accepted, and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From your discussion with adpeace I gather the library is targeting i386 whilst the the build commands you are using show clearly you are targeting an arm platform.

You will not have any luck using this particular library file in that case and would need to find an arm version of it.