# Cross-compile a library for arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

My issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558468/undefined-reference-to-despite-correct-link-order/24558574?noredirect=1#24558574) led to the solution/new problem that I naively built the external library I am using for my host machine.

Thus of course `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler throws a fit when it meets `elf32-i386` object files.

I originally built the library using:

```
./configure
make && make check
make install
```

So, now I thought I might be able to simply do:

```
make clean
./configure --host=arm-none-eabi
make && make check
make install
```

to fix it. Sadly mistaken.

I also tried `--build=x86` but it seems this is auto-detected anyway.

`CC=arm-none-eabi` also seemed to have no effect.

---

What do I need to do in order to be able to build this library for linking when compiling with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`?

Comment: I am not sure your question and answer are helpful without noting the package.  Each configure/make may have different needs.  For instance, some projects build programs meant to run on the host.

Comment: You are not even telling what the problem is, besides "it does not work".

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, I did. `elf32-i386` is obviously not desired to compile for `arm-none-eabi`.

Comment: @OllieFord: "throws a fit" is not really a good error description, is it?

Comment: @PlasmaHH What more is necessary? I didn't need to be told why I was getting that error. I knew why: the object files were for `elf32-i386`. The question was to how to properly build the library for the target arch. "Throws a fit" would be bad if I then said "why?", but I didn't, I said "because:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working with a couple of extra options specific to that `configure` script.

Though I didn't realise at the time of asking the question, these vary, so some familiarity or trial and error with the specific options available (`./configure --help` should always list those available) is required.

I should also note that `make check` will always fail on the build system, so isn't worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You using wrong cross compiler .

`arm-none-eabi` is used for bare metal programs.

Instead use arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc which will contain library to solve undefined behaviours.

Have a look @ [Cross compile error "arm-none-eabi-g++ cannot find entry symbol"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217425/cross-compile-error-arm-none-eabi-g-cannot-find-entry-symbol/21217588#21217588)

Comment: He appears to be building his own library package with configure for a bare metal device.